# Прозрачный текст относительно фона

Tags: css, css3

Допустим есть какой-либо прозрачный фон блока:
    `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);`
И на этом блоке отображается текст со следующим свойством:
    `color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);`
Фон сайта задан так:
    `body { background-image: url(../images/font1.jpg);}`

В итоге прозрачность текста видна относительно родительного элемента. 
Фон сайта не виден с такой прозрачностью текста.  
Как реализовать прозрачность текста к фону сайта в каком-либо элементе? 
Т.е. в итоге будет видна часть фона из текста.

Comment: Вам, видимо, нужен http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно таким образом.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700);

body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 1em;
    padding: 1em 1em .25em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 240px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-left: -120px;
    content: '';
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Clip text element */
.clip-text {
    font-size: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: .25em;
    padding: .5em .75em;
    text-align: center;
    /* Color fallback */
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.clip-text:before,
.clip-text:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}

/* Background */
.clip-text:before {
    z-index: -2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: inherit;
}

/* Text Background (black zone) */
.clip-text:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: .125em;
    right: .125em;
    bottom: .125em;
    left: .125em;
    background-color: #000;
}

/* Change the background position to display letter when the black zone isn't here */
.clip-text--no-textzone:before {
    background-position: -.65em 0;
}

.clip-text--no-textzone:after {
    content: none;
}

/* Use Background-size cover for photo background and no-repeat background */
.clip-text--cover,
.clip-text--cover:before {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}

/* Background image from http://thepatternlibrary.com/ and http://lorempixel.com */
.clip-text_one {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/7);
}

.clip-text_two {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract);
}

.clip-text_tree {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/2);
}

.clip-text_four {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/4);
}

.clip-text_five {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/5);
}

.clip-text_six {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/9);
}

.clip-text_seven {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/8);
}

.clip-text_eight {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/410/200/people);
}

.clip-text_nine {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/nightlife);
}

.clip-text_ten {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/nightlife/8);
}

.clip-text_eleven {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/fashion/10/cc);
    background-size: cover;
}

.clip-text_twelve {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/people/7/cc);
}

.clip-text_thirteen {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/food/5/cc);
}

.clip-text_fourteen {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/city/9/cc);
}

.clip-text_fifteen {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/nightlife/5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_one">Mask</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_fifteen clip-text--no-textzone">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_twelve clip-text--cover">Еще маска</div>
  <div class="clip-text clip-text_tree clip-text--no-textzone">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_two">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_fourteen clip-text--cover">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_tree">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_eleven clip-text--cover">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_four">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_five">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_six">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_seven">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_eight">Mask</div>
      
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_nine">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_ten">Mask</div>
      <div class="clip-text clip-text_thirteen clip-text--cover">Mask</div>
  </div>
```

Или так:

```css
html, body{ background: grey; }
p{ margin: 0px; }

#clip{
  /*
  Бекграунд добавлять первым
  */  
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, rgba(222,112,6,0.2), #de7006),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  
   background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  
  font-size: 28vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="clip">Другая маска</p>
```

Градиент.

```css
.gradient1 {
    font-size: 96px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
section.light {
    background: #eee;
}
.gradient1::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#23966c, #faaa54, #e23b4a, #db0768, #360670);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#23966c, #faaa54, #e23b4a, #db0768, #360670);
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<section class="light">
  <h1 class="gradient1">CSS Gradient Text</h1>
</section>
```