# Как сделать прозрачное «отверстие» в блоке с фоном(background)?

Tags: css

Ситуация такая что есть блок с `background`, нужно в нем сделать `отверстие(прозрачное)` чтобы можно было наблюдать что за фоном.

Есть ли реализация без внедрения `png` `svg` и тд?
Видел такую реализацию, но так и не понял как это было сделано

Есть ли какие-то идеи?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать прозрачный текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663012/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82)

Comment: Приведи код для которого нужно сделать. Дай ссылку на реализацию, которую видел

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет

Comment: @harbor что нет?

Comment: @Alex78191 видел в вконтакте при загрузке фото, там нужно выбрать миниатюру

Comment: @harbor, в том вопросе ответ Шиманского вроде бы подходит (ибо не использует SVG).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613156/178988 - вроде больше подходит?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну назвали бы вопрос по-человечески чтоб его можно найти через поиск - можно было и его предложить.... Хотя все равно там SVG, а нужен чистый css

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, предлагаешь переоткрыть как не дубликат?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, переоткрыл, т. к. просят без svg, а тут всё-таки ответ есть соответствующий.

Comment: @Qwertiy собственно в вопросе "Как сделать прозрачный текст?" тоже на css..... есть еще где-то дубль,... тпиа такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573321

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну этот вопрос явно не про текст.

Comment: @Qwertiy а какая разница? ну замени "текст" на круг/фигуру/символ/березу/космонавта  - смысл один

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, решения абсолютно разные.

Comment: @Qwertiy именно  поэтому стоило как раз добавить ответ в тот дубль, чтоб набрать решений и закрывать, по-сути, как каноническим

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно попробовать с помощью псевдоэлемента `:after` и огромной непрозрачной тени:

```css
  #hole {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #hole:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px #000;
  }

  body {
    background: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/Wallpaper-1.png');
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="hole" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а "так" - это как?

Comment: С помощью `:after`, там же видно. Или нужно каждый ответ сопровождать очевидными комментариями? Могу поправить, если требуется.

Comment: Ну вы тут знанием делитесь или выпендриваетесь? Да нужно пояснение, потому что если для вас тут все очевидно, то другим, кто ищет ответ на такую же проблему - вообще не ясно. Что делает after, почему так.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  
`:after` потому что лень отдельный элемент создавать