# Как сверстать прозрачный текст над полупрозрачным блоком и фоновой картинкой?

Tags: html, css, css3

друзья. Я созрел для вопроса. Как сверстать прозрачный текст над полупрозрачным блоком и фоновой картинкой? Лучше всего, наверное, проиллюстрировать картинкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, имеем блок с фоновой картинкой, над которой расположен нужный мне блок с полупрозрачным фоном. В нём хочу поместить текст, который и сам прозрачен, и родительский полупрозрачный блок в этом месте становится полностью прозрачным.
Вдумчиво  читал этот [вопрос с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573321/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) и понял, что там не то, что мне нужно. Вариант:

```css
html,
body {
  background: grey;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}

#clip {
  /* Бекграунд добавлять первым  */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, rgba(222, 112, 6, 0.2), #de7006), url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size: 28vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="clip">Другая маска</p>
```

ближе всего к моей задумке, но и он делает всё наоборот. Он делает родительский блок полностью прозрачным и его собственныйфон "просвечивает" сквозь текст. Задумался, а можно ли вообще реализовать мою задумку на html и css?

Comment: @Duoxx, к указанному вопросу отношения не имел, более того, я его не находил, так что, спасибо вам за ссылку. Изучу ответы в указанной вами теме.

Comment: @Duoxx, в указанной вами теме есть хороший ответ, набравший 13 баллов, тот, что с двумя фонами, но он не сработает при адаптивной вёрстке, так что вопрос всё ещё открыт.

Comment: Тогда только svg

Comment: Возникает только ещё идея с доработкой напильником, то есть на javascript, чтобы сдвиг второго фона вычислять относительно позиции родительского блока, но это уже другая история. Грустно. ((

Comment: можно на svg а можно просто вырезать в растровом редакторе текст и поместить на кнопку фоном

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Про полупрозрачные картинки, где сразу вырезана надпись - думал. Хорошо до той поры, пока не потребуется надпись сменить.

Comment: я согласен ... я про то если вдруг надо всего одну такую штуку сделать ... если менять надо то svg

Comment: @Quazimorda, если вам понравился мой ответ, то поставьте пожалуйста зеленую галочку

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
 background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqO3LPr7q6A1sBK9txDufqZDWrLB1I-iyRqSfCOBkwLBpumGxW);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
    <defs>
      <mask id="hole">
        <rect width="400" height="200" fill="white"/>
        <text y="110" font-size="40"  fill="black">Button</text> 
      </mask> 
    </defs>
    <rect y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)" mask="url(#hole)">
    </rect> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: По-моему вы просто взяли код отсюда — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663208/280567

Comment: Поставил минус, так как код был точь-в-точь "содран" с ответа в подобном вопросе

Comment: @Arthur не всё содрал, фон поставил свой :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, нужно добавить новый вариант удаления ответов — "Дубликат ответа в вопросе-дубликате":))

Comment: @Arthur остроумно :))

Comment: @Yernar может сами удалите ответ? И минус исчезнет И медальку бронзовую за это система добавит вам   - за удаление ответа по требованию сообщества - как-то так звучит